# TextureAtlas and renderCalls in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, textures, texture-atlas

I'm creating two textures and put them in the same TextureAtlas as shown in the code:

```
public void create () {
    pix = new Pixmap(100, 100, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas();

    pix.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pix.fill();
    textureAtlas.addRegion("white", new TextureRegion(new Texture(pix)));
    pix.setColor(Color.RED);
    pix.fill();
    textureAtlas.addRegion("red", new TextureRegion(new Texture(pix)));

    tr_list = textureAtlas.getRegions();

    pix.dispose()
}
```

and then when rendering:

```
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        batch.draw(tr_list.get(i % tr_list.size), (int)(Math.random()* 500), (int)(Math.random()* 500));
    }
    font.draw(batch, "FPS: " + Integer.toString(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()), 0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 20);
    font.draw(batch, "Render Calls: " + Integer.toString(batch.renderCalls), 0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 60);
    batch.end();
}
```

I was expecting batch.renderCalls to be equal to 1, since the textures are in the same TextureAtlas, but instead it's equal to 200. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to draw your `TextureRegions` in a single render call, each of them must be a part of the same `Texture`, not `TextureAtlas`.

`TextureAtlas` can contain `TextureRegions` of different `Textures`, which actually happens in your case. Even though you use the same `Pixmap`, you create two different `Textures` from it.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it. I thought TextureAtlas was taking care of putting different textures "together".

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing them in loop 200 times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
    // this will be called 200 times
    batch.draw(tr_list.get(i % tr_list.size), (int)(Math.random()* 500), (int)(Math.random()* 500)); 
}
```

And also `TextureAtlas` class doesn't create pig picture of textures that you add to it. It is just container of `TextureRegions` how @Arctic23 noticed.

So main problem for you is to draw 2 textures in one render call. I wouldn't recommend you doing this. It is possible but it will be hard to work with them.

Calling `batch.draw(..)` every time you draw a texture is not a big performance problem. So i don't know why you detach this.